# Excel - need to learn how to make it?

Tags: excel, project, vba

I am an architect and had a work sheet of numerous rooms in it. I had made a basic search engine in which you write down the specific code no of a room an the rest of the specification about that particular room appears in order.What i would like to add is a plus and minus signs over that search box to make it possible to seek for the next and previous code. Can you please help me?
Already now thank you for your replies:)

NOTE: I have no knowledge of Macro. If you are to explain please remember that you are explaining it to a rookie so assume that i even dont know how to kickstart it in the first place:)

Comment: Please can you show what you have so far? A screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First, to write a macro you must enable the "Developer" feature on your version of excel.

2007:
https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-or-run-in-developer-mode-1b4a8529-3094-432a-9a7f-53935089e5ed

2010/2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx

you will now have an extra pane, "Developer" in which you will find important stuff like: "Visual Basic", "Macro", etc..

The **Insert** button allows you to select a button or similar in your excel sheet. When doing so, you will be prompted to assign a macro to run, when the button is pushed.

even though the macro does not exist yet, you can create it by writing a fancy name for it, in this dialog, and click "new".
This will open a code editor in a new window.

---

Clicking on "Visual Basic" also opens the code editor. (In case you close it by accident)

In the code editor window, to the left, you'll see a "tree" with the sheets properties. To the right should be a text like:

```
Sub theNameYouChoseForTheMacro()

End Sub
```

*If not, then you will want to double click on "ThisWorkbook" to actually start editing the code.*

click on the text, in the line between "()" and "End".

**This is where we want to add the code for the button.**

Now depending how the search engine is made, the code needs to be written accordingly. The following assumes that it is a cell in a workbook.

first, we start out by reading the existing value in the search cell, and storing it in a variable with the dimension Integer (assuming your code is an integer?)
*notice that the cell is selected by its location in the sheet*

```
Dim myVariable
myVariable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

then we want to add or subtract a value, in this example we add a value:

```
myVariable = myVariable + 1
```

and write it back to the cell, to re-do the excel implemented search..

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = myVariable
```

in case you implemented the search with a plugin, or VBA code from somewhere, you will need to activate the search in some manner.

The complete example code:

```
Sub theNameYouChoseForTheMacro()
    Dim myVariable As Integer
    myVariable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    myVariable = myVariable + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = myVariable
End Sub
```

---

**post comment edits:**

> As far as i observe in order to raise the value by 1 myvariable+1 is defined as the next (after the double click) value for that particular cell.

Ehmnnn, Not sure I decode this text correctly, but.. 
Yes we simply add one to the value of the variable, and then write it back into the cell when done. This is not when you double click, it is when you left click the button. Or run the macro from the editor (click the play icon, and select *theNameYouChoseForTheMacro*

> But my room codes are made up of text and number combination ( ex: B2-021 means floor Basement 2 - room 21 ) .And these codes are not always raising in a steady manner

Ok.. That changes thing..

If you want to get the next code, we need the code to extract a description of all the possible codes for a building.
How do the codes relate to the room data in the excel sheet?

In the next version I assume you have one room per row, in a different sheet "Sheet2", and that the rooms code can be seen in coloumn A in Sheet2

First we need to know that the searched code is a string, not an Integer:

```
    Dim myVariable As String
    myVariable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

and we want to determine where it is located in Sheet2, for this I use a function, modified from a sub found in a macro stolen from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm

```
Function Find_First(FindString As String, Optional Col As Boolean)
    Dim Rng As Range
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                If Col Then
                    Find_First = Rng.Column
                Else
                    Find_First = Rng.Row
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
                Find_First = Nothing
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

This provides me with the coloumn and the row number of the found string in Sheet2.
So we take that row number and change it by adding or subtracting one
This time we get the value from the cell at column and row indexes:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim myVariable As String
    Dim Coloumn As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer

    myVariable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    Coloumn = Find_First(myVariable, True)
    Row = Find_First(myVariable) + 1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Row, Coloumn)

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply and detailed explanation on the issue Henrik:) I quiet get what you have ment by your macro text and will adapt it into mine. As far as i observe in order to raise the value by 1 myvariable+1 is defined as the next (after the double click) value for that particular cell. But my room codes are made up of text and number combination ( ex: B2-021 means floor Basement 2 - room 21 ) .And these codes are not always raising in a steady manner.

Comment: In this case i should be defining myvariable as a particular cell and within the next round i should state that if my variable is A1 it should consider it as A2 so that it will always check out for the next one. And for the minus sign macro i should state the opposite

Comment: -1
down vote
accept
WOW:) of course its kind of mind blowing for me at this stage but yeah i will try to understand the logic within. Only thing that might not be quiet fit in with my sheet can be column and row indexes though i just need it to get information from a certain coloumn. If it's okey with you, i can share the .xls so that you can have a better look. I will take notes on it to describe the desired process. I am new at stack over flow though, is it possible to share .xls with an other user ?

And again thank you Henrik, for the effort to teach me some macro and solve my problem:)

Comment: It is not atm. possible to host files on stack overflow (except images, via the insert image button.) look here for the faq discussion on this subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources

(It is also bad etiquette to send a file, which I would edit, and send it back, without doing it publicly.) I recommend screenshots, for exchanging data on excel structures.

Comment: for getting information from a specific column, look at  `With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")` the _A:A_ part sets which colomn to look in for the room code..